# Focus not moved to inputbox() and box remains behind of apps (Vista)

Tags: delphi

How can I make my delphi  systray app using standard vcl inputbox() function to request focus, now dialog box seem to remain in taskbar and dialog does not open to front of other apps. This is Vista issue I think.   Creating own form would solve it I believe.

ps: I can edit dialogs.pas if needed, it seem to be using Tcustomforms.showmodal

Comment: Because your app isn't in the foreground, the OS is preventing you from popping up a dialog over everything else; after all, it would be a focus stealing piece of evil. There are hacks and workarounds to try to steal focus, but [you really really really should not do this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using older version of delphi.

Some Vista specific workarounds for older delphi versions can be fond [here](http://www.theabsolute.net/sware/delphivista.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try `Application.ProcessMessages;` just before inputbox call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an  `application.BringtoFront()`  before you launch the inputbox?

Editing dialogs.pas seems to be a bad ide. I would rather make my own inputbox-form.

Applications stealing focus can be quite annoying, though... How do you launch the inputbox? On a timer, or on a userrequest (e.g. clicking on the icon)?

Comment: BringtoFront did not do anything, however I dont have Application main form at all,  this is Systray background app..